# Binomial model with GAM (mgcv) using weights

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

I have been having an issue when trying to fit a binomial GAM to data. There are two ways these models can be coded, (i) providing a proportion as the response variable, and the number of trials as weights; and (ii) providing two columns, with successes and failures. I have reason to want to weight my data points (independently of the number of samples). However, I have noticed that if I use approach (ii) and add weights (using the `weights` argument), I get very odd results indeed. Furthermore, if I supply the same weights in relative terms (but different absolute magnitudes), I get very different output. This does not happen when using an equivalent GLM model (or, indeed, when using the `gam` package). How can I provide a set of weights for the data points?

Here is a MRE:

```
library('mgcv')

# Random data.
x = 1:100
y_binom = cbind(rpois(100, 5 + x/2), rpois(100, 100))
w = sample(seq_len(100), 100, replace = TRUE)

# GAM models.
m1 = gam(y_binom ~ s(x), family = 'binomial')
m2 = gam(y_binom ~ s(x), weights = w / mean(w), family = 'binomial')
m3 = gam(y_binom ~ s(x), weights = w / sum(w), family = 'binomial')
m4 = gam(y_binom ~ s(x), weights = w * 100, family = 'binomial')

ms = list(m1, m2, m3, m4)

# Different RMSEs.
lapply(X = ms, FUN = function(x) return(sqrt(mean(x$residuals^2))))

# Different predictions, e.g.
plot(predict(m2), predict(m3))


# This does not happen with GLMs.
m1 = glm(y_binom ~ x, family = 'binomial')
m2 = glm(y_binom ~ x, weights = w / mean(w), family = 'binomial')
m3 = glm(y_binom ~ x, weights = w / sum(w), family = 'binomial')
m4 = glm(y_binom ~ x, weights = w * 100, family = 'binomial')

ms = list(m1, m2, m3, m4)

# Same RMSEs (for m2-m4).
lapply(X = ms, FUN = function(x) return(sqrt(mean(x$residuals^2))))

# Same predictions, e.g.
plot(predict(m2), predict(m3))
```

Comment: This should really be asked on [stats.se]; this isn't a question about programming

Comment: Happy to do that, but considering the different behaviours of `glm`, `mgcv::gam`, and `gam::gam` and lack of information in the documentation, it didn't feel out of place here, unless you mean that this is indeed the intended behaviour in `mgcv::gam`.

Comment: Confirming that you get different behaviour fitting the *same* model in `glm` & `gam` (i.e. without smooths) would be interesting. From `?gam`, there is a note about `weights` changing the magnitude of the log-likelihood & that normalization is required if you don't want to change it: "If you want to re-weight the contributions of each datum without changing the overall magnitude of the log likelihood, then you should normalize the weights (e.g. `weights <- weights/mean(weights)`)". As there is no such warning in `?glm`, I suspect the way that `weights` are handled does differ btw the two

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are seeing a difference because of an issue where smooths have difficulty and not any inherent problem in the GLM part of the model; your choice of weights is changing the magnitude of the log-likelihood which is resulting in slightly different models being returned.

I'll get back to that shortly. First, the "problem" goes away if you just fit a common or garden GLM with `gam()`:

```r
library('mgcv')

# Random data
set.seed(1)
x <- 1:100
y_binom <- cbind(rpois(100, 5 + x/2), rpois(100, 100))
w <- sample(seq_len(100), 100, replace = TRUE)

gam_m <- gam(y_binom ~ x, weights = w / mean(w), family = 'binomial')
glm_m <- glm(y_binom ~ x, weights = w / mean(w), family = 'binomial')
```

Exactly the same model is fitted

```r
> logLik(gam_m)
'log Lik.' -295.6122 (df=2)
> logLik(glm_m)
'log Lik.' -295.6122 (df=2)
> coef(gam_m)
(Intercept)           x 
 -2.1698127   0.0174864 
> coef(glm_m)
(Intercept)           x 
 -2.1698127   0.0174864
```

and even if you change the magnitude of the log-likelihood by using a different normalization of the weights, you get the same fitted model even though the log+likelihood is different:

```r
gam_other <- gam(y_binom ~ x, weights = w / sum(w), family = 'binomial')
```

```
> logLik(gam_other)
'log Lik.' -2.956122 (df=2)
> coef(gam_other)
(Intercept)           x 
 -2.1698127   0.0174864
```

The behaviour of `glm()` is that same in this regard:

```r
> logLik(glm(y_binom ~ x, weights = w / sum(w), family = 'binomial'))
'log Lik.' -2.956122 (df=2)

# compare with logLik(gam_other)
```

This might break down in cases where the optimisation is more marginal, and this is what's happening with `gam()`. Using my *gratia* package we can easily compare the two GAMs fitted above:

```r
# using your GAM m2 and m3 as examples
library(gratia)
comp <- compare_smooths(m2, m3)
draw(comp)
```

which produces

[image]

Note that by default, that smooths in those plots include a correction related to bias introduced when the smooth is estimated to be linear.

As you can see, the two fits are different; with one optimization penalising the smooth all the way back to a linear function and the other not quite penalizing as far. With more data, the extra complexity involved in fitting this model over a GLM (where in the GAM we're having to select smoothness parameters), would be overcome and I would expect the change to the log-likelihood to not have such a dramatic effect.

This situation is one where a some of the theory about GAMs starts to get a little looser there's work to try to correct or account for these issues, but often it can be difficult to tell the difference between something that is linear or slightly non-linear on the scale of the link function. Here the true function is slightly non-linear on the scale of the link function but `m3` isn't able to identify this, in part I think because the weights are dominating the likelihood calculation.

Comment: Thank you for the really helpful reply! So, if I understand correctly, the issue is that despite using the same relative differences in weights, it's the absolute likelihood values that are used in the optimization, and with larger absolute values of the weights there are bigger differences in likelihood. If so, it's really tricky to really know what the right absolute values of weights should be (except maybe following the documentation's suggestion of keeping the likelihood the same by using `weights = weights / mean(weights)`). In any case, thank you for helping clarify the issue.

Comment: I don't have my copy of Simon Wood's GAM book to hand to check, but I believe that is the case; the log-likelihoods of the models with different absolute `weights` are different even when we have estimated the same coefficients so the `weights` *are* changing the likelihood. I don't think it is that tricky; just normalize the weights so that they have 0 average contribution as the help suggests. The weights are interpreted relatively; though `?gam` doesn't say this explicitly, it is implied by the note about a weight of 2 counting double (the default weight is 1, but this is not stated)